# How would I convert a 10 digit numeric field to have only two positions after the decimal?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here is the SQL statement I currently have:

```
CAST(ISNULL(slp.WEIGHT, 0) AS numeric(10, 2)) AS shipweight
```

It is producing for example 291659.399999999, what I want is 291659.40.

Comment: I don't have a problem with this. Here's the sample code that I used: `DECLARE @WEIGHT numeric(20,10)
SET @WEIGHT = 291659.3999999999
SELECT @WEIGHT, CAST(ISNULL(@WEIGHT, 0) AS numeric(10, 2)) AS shipweight`

Answer (score 0):

```
 CAST(ISNULL(slp.WEIGHT, 0) AS decimal(10, 2)) AS shipweight
```

This should work...

Comment: DECIMAL and NUMERIC are the same data type. see:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [ROUND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) function instead of using CAST. IMO, using the ROUND function will be more clear that you're rounding the value and more readable.